# How to modify the HTML and BODY tags in an ASP.NET page without adding runat=server to the elements?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, localization

In an ASP.NET web forms project that is not quite ready to be upgraded from 2.0 to 4.0 , there is a change that needs to be made to allow modifications to the HTML and BODY tags on the pages without adding runat=server to the tags which results in the 2.0 styled "ugly ids" like "ctrl_100..."

For example, how could we change these using JavaScript, a Response Filter (the regex to find these specific tags would really help on this one), or something else...from:

```
<html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
```

To:

```
<html lang="jp=JP" xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<body dir="rtl">
```

JavaScript seems like a possibility, but functions from the server-side could would determine the language and direction the page should have.

Comment: If you are using master pages your Client ID will be decorated. That's why you are receiving those ugly names.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for removing the '123456' - it wouldn't let me edit the formatting without adding text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace Website
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string HtmlAttributes()
        {
             return " lang='jp=JP' dir='rtl'";
        }
        public static string BodyAttributes()
        {
             return " dir='rtl'";
        }
    }
}

<html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"<%= Website.Utils.HtmlAttributes()%>>
<body<%= Website.Utils.BodyAttributes()%>>
```

If you are sure that there are always some attributes you can remove the first whitespace and add it in markup.

I prefer this method to the javascript method because with the latest the search engines can't know what language or what direction has the html page.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use jQuery it would make your life easier. You could set some hidden fields with the values from your server first and use those to get your values in jquery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(function(){
          var dir = $("[id$='whatever_you_named_your_hidden_field']").val();
          var lang = $("[id$='whatever_you_named_your_second_hidden_field']").val();

          $('body').attr('dir', dir);
          $('html').attr('lang', lang).attr('dir', dir);
       });

    </script>
```

**Edit**
Updated my answer based on Chamika Sandamal's answer

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jQuery, you can getrid of those ugly names by using following jQuery code,

```
$("[id$='actualId']")
```

Comment: yes. concept is , it is returning the element that containing id ends with actual id. so you no need to hardcode that generated ugly id

Comment: although, is there a missing `]` on the end?

Comment: @csharpsi: oh i didnt see it.thanks for pointing out that typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4 you can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the page directive which then forces the ID of the element to remain the same, hence making accessing it from JavaScript much easier.

You could then use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to add some JavaScript from the code behind to manipulate the elements.